# Slight between function not working with custom function

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I am a beginner trying to write a sqlite query

Why

```py
data = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM ACCESS WHERE TIME BETWEEN "2020-11-19 00:00:00" AND "2020-11-20 00:00:00" ''')
```

Work's

but

```py
def withtime (a,b):

    data = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM ACCESS WHERE TIME BETWEEN (A,B) values (?,?)''',(a,b)
```

Withtime("2020-11-19 00:00:00","2020-11-20 00:00:00")

Doesn't work?

Comment: Please elaborate "Doesn't work"?

Comment: Consider providing a MRE as described in your second  tags wiki info.

Comment: What are your thought? Can you for example describe the intended differences of the two code pieces? I ask because the problem is likely in the uninteded differences.

Comment: I am a little better with python than with sqlite... Tim's code below helped me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in your second query is off and is not valid SQL.  The following version should work:

```py
sql = 'SELECT * FROM ACCESS WHERE TIME >= ? AND TIME < ?'
times = ('2020-11-19', '2020-11-20',)
c.execute(sql, times)
```

The above query would return all records whose `TIME` falls precisely on 19th November, 2020.  Note that your current query, as you wrote it with `BETWEEN`, actually would include midnight of 20th November, 2020.  To avoid this, use an inequality, as I have done above.